# How does Hatcher conclude that the set of points where $\tilde f_1$ and $\tilde f_2$ agree is both open and closed?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

The last line of the proof he notes that the set of points where $\tilde f_1$ and $\tilde f_2$ agree is both open and closed.

**How does this follow from the argument?**

---

> [image]

Comment: The argument states that if $\tilde{f}_1$ and $\tilde{f}_2$ agree at some $y$, there exists some open subset $y \in U \subset \tilde{X}$ on which the two functions agree. So, $S=\{y,\,\tilde{f}_1(y)=\tilde{f}_2(y)\}$ is open. On the other hand, $S=(\tilde{f}_1,\tilde{f}_2)^{-1}(\Delta)$ where $\Delta \subset \tilde{X} \times \tilde{X}$ is the diagonal, thus is closed if $\tilde{X}$ is Hausdorff (iff $X$ is). So under usual assumptions, $S$ is closed as well.

Comment: If $\tilde f_1(y)=\tilde f_2(y)$, then $\tilde f_1$ and $\tilde f_2$ agree on a neighborhood of $y$, this means the set where they agree is open. Before that, he showed in a similar manner that the complement is open.

Comment: @Mindlack: I think Hausdorff plays no role here. The functions differ on an open set because the respective images of $y$ are in distinct sheets of $p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @ Stefan Hamcke: right, I have forgotten that we dealt even in this part with liftings of the same map $Y \rightarrow X$, thanks!

Comment: As stated in the other comments, you can show beforehand that for every *covering map* $p \colon E \to B$ the diagonal $\Delta$ is open and closed in the *fiber product* $E \times_p E = \{(e_1, e_2) : p(e_1) = p(e_2)\}$. The set over which the two liftings agree is $(\tilde{f}_1, \tilde{f}_2)^{-1}(\Delta)$, which is then both open and closed. If $Y$ is connected this implies that the set over which the two liftings agree is either $\emptyset$ or $Y$; in particular if you assume that they agree over a point then it has to be the whole $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The comment section is too short to post this, hence this non-answer.

Let $p \colon E \twoheadrightarrow B$ be a covering map, we want to show that
$\Delta_E$ is both open and closed in the fibred product
$$E \times_p E = \{(e_1, e_2) : p(e_1) = p(e_2)\}.$$
Here follows the proof in lenghty details.

---

**Open:**

Let $e \in E$, we want to show that there exists an open subset
$A \subseteq E \times_p E$ such that $(e, e) \in A \subseteq \Delta_E$.

Let $U$ be an evenly covered open neighbourhood of $p(e)$, and let
$V$ be the sheet (one of the opens in which the preimage of $U$ decomposes)
containing $e$. Then the restriction
$$p_| \colon V \to U$$
is a homeomorphism, and in particular it is *injective*.
The subset
$$V \times_p V = (V \times V) \cap (E \times_p E) =
\{(e_1, e_2) \in V \times V : p(e_1) = p(e_2)\}$$
is an open neighbourhood of $(e, e)$. We want to show that it is contained
in $\Delta_E$.

Indeed, let $(e_1, e_2) \in V \times_p V$. Then $p(e_1) = p(e_2)$, and by *injectivity* $e_1 = e_2$, that is $(e_1, e_2) \in \Delta_E$.

---

**Closed:**

We prove that the complement $\Delta_E^c = E \times_p E \setminus \Delta_E$
is open. To do this, we adopt the same idea as before,
except that this time we use two (disjoint) sheets.

Let $(e_1, e_2) \in \Delta_E^c$, meaning $e_1 \neq e_2$
and $p(e_1) = p(e_2)$.

Let $U$ be an evenly covered open neighbourhood of $p(e_i)$ and let
$V_i$ be the sheet containing $e_i$. The open subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint by definition of covering map.

The subset
$$V_1 \times_p V_2 = (V_1 \times V_2) \cap (E \times_p E)$$
is an open neighbourhood of $(e_1, e_2)$. To show that $V_1 \times_p V_2$
is contained in $\Delta_E^c$, it is enough to use the fact that
$V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint.